# Data type confusion when inheriting ToString() from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, matrix

I am writing a class library in C# for working with matrices, and am currently working on a subclass of Matrix called ComplexMatrix. The Matrix base class works with values of the Int32 data type (a more advanced version uses Double), and the ComplexMatrix of the System.Numerics.Complex structure (.NET 4).

For the base class, I overrode ToString() as:

```
| 1 2 |
| 3 4 |    printed as    {{1,2}{3,4}}
```

The System.Numerics.Complex structure overrides ToString() in the form:

```
a+bi    printed as    (a,b)    where a is real and b is imaginary
```

When overriding ToString in ComplexMatrix, I simply used the method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, for a complex matrix, the following occurred:

```
| 1+1i 1+2i |
| 2+1i 2+2i |   printed as   {{0,0}{0,0}} rather than {{(1,1),(1,2)}{(2,1)(2,2)}}
```

The original ToString() code I wrote for the Matrix class is:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder matrixString = new StringBuilder();
    string comma = "";

    matrixString.Append("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Rows; i++)
    {
        matrixString.Append("{");
        for (int j = 0; j < this.Columns; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0) comma = "";
            else comma = ",";

            matrixString.Append(comma + this.Elements[i, j].ToString());
        }
        matrixString.Append("}");
    }
    matrixString.Append("}");
    return matrixString.ToString();
}
```

In the above code:

- this.Elements Property: in the Matrix class, this is a 2-dimensional array of Int32 type (Double in a newer, more advanced version); it is of System.Numerics.Complex type in ComplexMatrix
- this.Rows, this.Columns Properties: the number of rows and columns respectively of the matrix

Several questions I have are:

- When ToString is called on a ComplexMatrix instance, and calls the base ToString() method, is an attempted type conversion taking place from Complex to Int32?
- As the ComplexMatrix Elements property (Complex[,] type) is hiding the base class Elements property (Int32[,] type), the new keyword is required?
- Is the "this" kwyword being seen as a Matrix type rather than ComplexMatrix?

Comment: just a note.  `public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString();
}` you might as well remove that.

Comment: Another note not related to the issue. I think you have your class hierarchy upside down. The base class should always be the more general case, not the way around. Therefore DoubleMatrix should inherit form ComplexMatrix as a double is in a way a subclass of a complex number. This way you only need a Complex[,] array as the storage of the matrix elements defined in the base case that is able to store complex and doubles (you would just need to define an implicit cast between double and complex numbers). An int matrix would inherit DoubleMatrix though I fail to see the use of an int Matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the following:
The `Elements` property is not marked `virtual` in the `Matrix` class. The `Elements` property in the `ComplexMatrix` class hides the `Elements` property of the `Matrix` class. Therefore polymorphism isn't working and the `ToString` method in `Matrix` accesses `Matrix.Elements` and not `ComplexMatrix.Elements`. But because `Elements` is a property and you want to change the type of the property, you can't use `virtual` anyway.

To fix the problem, you should do something like this:

- Create a generic base class that wants the type of the matrix values as generic parameter
- Create a `SimpleMatrix` class that inherits from this base class and passes `int` as generic parameter.
- Create a `ComplexMatrix` class that inherits from this base class and passes `Complex` as generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you are trying to do.

The problem is that there is no superclass for all of the numeric types in C#. So you can't really substitute one numeric type for another in a class heirarchy like this (and still do math on them).

What you could do is create an IMatrixElement interface. Then create the concrete classes MatrixElementInt, MatrixElementDouble, MatrixElementComplex that implement that interface. Then supply the correct element type when constructing your matrix.

```
interface IMatrixElement
{
    IMatrixElement Add(IMatrixElement a, IMatrixElement b);
    IMatrixElement Multiply(IMatrixElement a, IMatrixElement b);
    string ToString();
}
```

Comment: when, oh when will they include operator constraints for generics...Matrix<T> would be lovely